# Why is the divergence of $\widehat{r}/r^2$ equal to $0$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I have read that $\nabla\cdot\dfrac{\widehat{r}}{r^2}$ is equal to $0$.

But I cannot understand why. I tried but I cannot solve it. Can anyone explain it please?

Comment: what is a and r?

Comment: ..and what is Del or (Del).a ...?

Comment: r is the radius vector of a sphere

Comment: Del here means $\nabla$ and the question is about the divergence of a vector function.

Comment: This is only true in a three-dimensional space.

Comment: Crossposted from http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/148239/2451

Answer (score 1):

If you [put it into spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates) (link to Wikipedia article "Del in cylindrical and spherical coordinates"), 
$$
\nabla\cdot{\hat{r}\over r^2}=1/r^2{\partial\over\partial r} {r^2\hat{r}\over r^2}
$$
$$
=1/r^2{\partial\over\partial r} \hat{r}
$$
Assuming $r\neq 0$, this is zero because $\hat{r}$ doesn't change with $r$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{}$
\begin{align}
\color{#66f}{\large\nabla\cdot\pars{\hat{r} \over r^{2}}}&
=\nabla\cdot\pars{{1 \over r^{3}}\,\vec{r}}
=\nabla\pars{1 \over r^{3}}\cdot\vec{r} + {1 \over r^{3}}\,\nabla\cdot\vec{r}
=\bracks{\hat{r}\,\totald{}{r}\pars{1 \over r^{3}}}\cdot\vec{r}
+ {1 \over r^{3}}\times 3
\\[5mm]&=\bracks{{\vec{r} \over r}\pars{-\,{3 \over r^{4}}}}\cdot\vec{r}
+{3 \over r^{3}}
=-\,{3 \over r^{3}}+ {3 \over r^{3}}=\color{#66f}{\Large 0}\,,\qquad \vec{r} \not= 0
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

This is not zero everywhere.  Use the integral definition of divergence.  Let $M$ be a volume centered on a point $p$.  Let $V$ be the volume of this region.

$$\left. \nabla \cdot \frac{\hat r}{r^2} \right|_p = \lim_{V \to 0} \frac{1}{V} \oint_{p \in M} \frac{\hat r}{r^2} \cdot \hat n \, dS$$

In particular, when $p$ is the origin, use spherical coordinates and a spherical integration volume.  Then $\hat n = \hat r$ and $dS = r^2 \sin \theta \, d\theta \, d\phi$, and we get

$$\left . \nabla \cdot \frac{\hat r}{r^2}  \right|_\vec{0} = \lim_{R \to 0} \frac{4\pi R}{4\pi R^3/3} $$

which diverges.  This only happens at the origin. At all other points, you can use the differential form of the divergence and get the right answer--which is zero.